# Exibir valor no While apenas no primeiro registro

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um while, mas preciso que seja exibido o valor **active** apenas no primeiro item `<div class="item ACTIVE">`.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php $exibir = "active"; do { ?>
  <div class="item ACTIVE">
    <h1 class="title">
      <?php echo $row_rsBanner["titulo"]; ?>
      <span class="subtitle"><?php echo $row_rsBanner["mensagem"]; ?></span></h1>
    <div class="car-img">
      <img src="img/car1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="car1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } while ($row_rsBanner = $rsBanner->fetch_assoc()); ?>
</div>
```

Como fazer para exibir apenas no primeiro loop e nos demais não?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uai, se for oque eu to pensando é bem simples, coloca um $i = 0; fora do while, quando ele passar no while vc coloca $i++, onde você quer mostrar o valor vc colocar

```
if($i == 1){<div></div>}
```

Comment: Consegue me ajudar com essa? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/366909/whire-entre-hora-inicial-e-final-com-m%C3%BAltiplos-de-30-minutos