# Whire entre hora inicial e final com múltiplos de 30 minutos

Tags: php

Olá.
Como fazer um `While` entre uma hora **inicial** / **final** e em **múltiplos de 30 minutos**.

**Exemplo:**

```
<option value="08:00">08:00</option>
<option value="08:30">08:30</option>
<option value="09:00">09:00</option>
<option value="09:30">09:30</option>
.
.
.
<option value="20:00">20:00</option>
```

Meu código

```
<select name="pick-up-time" id="pick-up-time">
  <?php 
    $horaInicial = "08:00";
    $horaFinal = "20:00";

    do{ 
  ?>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
  <?php } while ($row_rsLoja = $rsLoja->fetch_assoc()); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Eu não entendi direito, você quer gerar um option com valor de 30 mintuos por 24h?

Comment: Preciso fazer o loop pegando a hora inicial até a final, só que exibindo de 30 em 30 minutos, como no exemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Para quem tiver a mesma dúvida, achei um site que tinha um modelo similar, então só adaptei para o que eu queria.

Pena que o código é grande...rsrs, acredito que uma pessoa com conhecimento consegue reduzir para algumas linhas...rsrs

```
<select name="pick-up-time" id="pick-up-time">
<?php
    $timeFormat = "%02d:%02d";
    $startHour = "06:00";
    $endHour = "22:00";
    $timeInterval = 30; // in minutes

    $currentHour = $startHour;
    $currentMinute = 0;
    while ($currentHour <= $endHour) {
        $timeRange = sprintf($timeFormat, $currentHour, $currentMinute);

        $currentMinute = $currentMinute + $timeInterval;
        if ($currentMinute > 59) {
            $currentHour++;
            $currentMinute = $currentMinute - 60;
        }

        if ($currentHour <= $endHour) {
            echo "<option value=\"$timeRange\">$timeRange</option>";
        }       
    }

?>
</select>
```